# Add Distinct or GroupBy to LINQ query

Tags: linq, left-join, distinct

```
var listNews = await (from l in _context.Newss
                    join si in _context.AssignSites on l.NewsId equals si.ParentId into sij
                    from subsi in sij.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join se in _context.AssignSections on l.NewsId equals se.ParentId into sej
                    from subse in sej.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join me in _context.AssignMembers on l.NewsId equals me.ParentId into mej
                    from subme in mej.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where subsi.Site == user.BelongSite || subse.SectionName == user.Section ||       subme.FaxCode == user.UserName || l.CreatedBy == user.FullName
                    orderby l.CreatedWhen descending
                    select new NewsIndexVm{
                        Id = l.NewsId,
                        Title = l.NewsTitle,
                        Thumbnail = l.Thumbnail,
                        CreatedBy = l.CreatedBy,
                        CreatedWhen = l.CreatedWhen,
                        BelongSite = l.BelongSite
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
```

I'm trying to add group by or distinct to this query to remove duplicate items from query result but got some error. If I add `.Distinct()` before `.ToListAsync()`, the `orderby` clause will dissappear when translate to sql syntax. If I add `Distinct()` after materialize query, I still see duplicate records in result.

**Edit:** I found the solution, just take the orderby and distinct out of linq like this:

```
var listNews = await (from l in _context.Newss
                join si in _context.AssignSites on l.NewsId equals si.ParentId into sij
                from subsi in sij.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join se in _context.AssignSections on l.NewsId equals se.ParentId into sej
                from subse in sej.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join me in _context.AssignMembers on l.NewsId equals me.ParentId into mej
                from subme in mej.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where subsi.Site == user.BelongSite || subse.SectionName == user.Section || subme.FaxCode == user.UserName || l.CreatedBy == user.FullName
                select new NewsIndexVm{
                    Id = l.NewsId,
                    Title = l.NewsTitle,
                    Thumbnail = l.Thumbnail,
                    CreatedBy = l.CreatedBy,
                    CreatedWhen = l.CreatedWhen,
                    BelongSite = l.BelongSite
                })
                .Distinct()
                .OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreatedWhen)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You have duplicates because you have used joins without taking care of their cardinality. Explicit joins almost never needed if you have defined navigation properties. Show your model classes first.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv there are no relation between table News and AssignSites, AssignSections, AssignMembers, also there are no navigation property in model News, anyway thanks for your help